# babel-generator Invalid mapping when writing AST

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, babeljs

While writing a plugin that injects code from another file ... another file is transformed and injected into the AST of the original file

```
astB = babel.transformFileSync(templatename, { plugins:plugins, code:false});
```

after that, calling:

```
generate(ast, { sourceMaps: true, retainLines: false, quotes:"'"}, codes);
```

causes error

```
Error: Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":30,"column":0},"original":{"line":1,"column":0}}
at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (node_modules\babel-generator\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:289:13)
at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (node_modules\babel-generator\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:101:12)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at SourceMap.get (node_modules\babel-generator\lib\source-map.js:49:25)
at Object.get [as map] (node_modules\babel-generator\lib\buffer.js:53:33)
at writeAst (test2.js:59:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (test2.js:55:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not very obvious from the error, but the problem is that injected code called parser as part of the transformation, and did not provide file name.

changing the line with transform fixes the issue

adding `parserOpts:{sourceFilename: templatename}` the code becomes:

```
astB = babel.transformFileSync(templatename, {parserOpts:{sourceFilename: templatename}, plugins:plugins, code:false});
```